# m-systems and n-systems in topological rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings, topological-algebras, topological-rings

Note that throughout rings have a multiplicative identity and are *not necessarily commutative*

> **Definition**:  Let $R$ be a ring and let $M\subseteq R$.  Then, $M$ is an *m-system* iff for every $x,y\in M$ there is some $f\in R$ such that $xfy\in M$.
>
> **Definition**:  Let $R$ be a ring and let $N\subseteq R$.  Then, $N$ is an *n-system* iff for every $x\in N$ there is some $f\in R$ such that $xfx\in N$.

For what it's worth, these definitions are designed so that an ideal is prime (resp. radical) iff its complement is an *m*-system (resp. *n*-system).  (These terms actually come from Lam's book on noncommutative rings, where he uses the term "semiprime" instead of "radical".)

In the case $R$ carries a topology, I would like to prove the following.

> **Conjecture**:  Let $R$ be a topological ring, let $N\subseteq R$ be an open *n*-system, and let $f\in N$.  Then, there is an open *m*-system $f\in M\subseteq N$.

This is a generalization of [Lam's Lemma 10.10](https://books.google.com/books?id=2PwGCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA167) and the reason I care about it is because I would like to show that the smallest closed radical ideal containing a closed ideal $I$ is the intersection of all closed prime ideals containing $I$.

Unlike most of Lam's results in this section, the solution here does not seem to be a straightforward generalization of his arguments, and I'm beginning to suspect it might not even be true.

Any ideas on how best to proceed?